# Is there a way to make Windows calculator always follow Order of Operations?

Tags: windows-7, calculator

When I type `5 + 5 * 6` into the windows calculator I get `60`. It appears as if windows ignores order of operations.

One potential solution is to [change the registry keys](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2005/02/09/370264.aspx) so that it starts in Scientific Mode (View > Scientific, or Alt-F2), where it does follow order of operations.

I prefer if the users weren't exposed to all the additional buttons in Scientific Mode or I didn't have to replace the default calculator with a third party solution. I realize these might be the only two options. I am just wondering if someone else has come up with a solution that I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: You can force the operation order by entering 5 + (5*6) but that's probably too annoying to make everybody do all the time.

Comment: It doesn't ignore the order of operations. It calculates them in the order as you type them in. Every operation is processed individually. Once you type `5+5`, it will already print the result, `10`. If you want to delay execution you simply have to chose another mode of operation.

Comment: Use better software. http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-calculator.htm

Comment: [Order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) **doesn't** mean the order you type them in.  I've always just used brackets.

Comment: in non-scientific mode it behaves like all non-scientific pocket calculators, which doesn't have a stack to remember the operator precedence

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want try some script, I specifically made ​​this script for you, this is autoit script, if you can not understand, I could give compiled code, basically the script will change the look of the default Windows calculator into which you want,

```
If Not WinExists("[CLASS:CalcFrame]") Then Run("calc.exe")
WinWait("[CLASS:CalcFrame]")

For $i = 29 to 55
    $ins = "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:" & $i & "]"
    ControlMove( "[CLASS:CalcFrame]", "", $ins, -100, -100)
Next

For $i = 1 to 28
    $ins = "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:" & $i & "]"
    $pos = ControlGetPos ( "[CLASS:CalcFrame]", "", $ins)
    ControlMove( "[CLASS:CalcFrame]", "", $ins, $pos[0] - 206, $pos[1] -65)
Next

ControlMove( "[CLASS:CalcFrame]", "", "[CLASS:Static; INSTANCE:6]", -100, -100)
ControlMove( "[CLASS:CalcFrame]", "", "[CLASS:Static; INSTANCE:7]", -100, -100)

$pos = ControlGetPos ( "[CLASS:CalcFrame]", "", "[CLASSNN:#327701; INSTANCE:1]")
ControlMove( "[CLASS:CalcFrame]", "", "[CLASSNN:#327701; INSTANCE:1]", $pos[0] -182, $pos[1] ,$pos[2],$pos[3])
ControlMove( "[CLASS:CalcFrame]", "", "[CLASS:Static; INSTANCE:1]", $pos[0] -182, $pos[1] ,$pos[2],$pos[3])

$pos = WinGetPos ("[CLASS:CalcFrame]")
WinMove ( "[CLASS:CalcFrame]", "", $pos[0], $pos[1] ,$pos[2] - 195,$pos[3])

$hWnd = WinGetHandle ("[CLASS:CalcFrame]")
DllCall("user32.dll", "bool", "RedrawWindow", "hwnd", $hWnd, "struct*", 0, "handle", 0, "uint", 5)
```

Comment: as asking "It would be ideal if the users were not exposed to all the additional buttons in Scientific Mode" this script modify scientific calc additional buttons.

Comment: no, you don't need to keep runing this script, this script only running 2 second before calculator start, in other words, this script is a calculator launcher, you can put it on your desktop and click him if you want to open calculator.